# How secure is encryption in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, encryption

How secure is encryption in Access 2007?

Comment: Not a meaningful question unless you specify the purpose for which you are evaluating using it. That is, for some purposes it's sufficient, for others, it's not.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the .ACCDB format and change the default encryption, it could be very secure.  An [article by Wayne Phillips](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Changing-the-encryption-type-in-Access-2007&Rated=V5) has some good information on how to do that.  According to the article, the default encryption is 40-bit RC4, which is not very secure and can be broken quickly.

You can apparently change the encryption to other options such as 256-bit AES, though. It is currently not considered feasible to be able to break a 256-bit symmetric key by brute force. So the biggest issue then most likely becomes a question of using it correctly. If someone chooses a 3 character password, then 256-bit AES still is not going to help very much. Nor would it help if the password is strong but is stored in a text file.

Comment: Very useful and informative post -- especially the cited URL. Thanks for this, and +1. And great avatar image!

Comment: @David: Thanks!  My daughter drew the picture for me; I'll pass on the compliment to her.